# Запятая и тире на стыке

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастный-оборот, вставная-конструкция, запятые

**Сославшись на непреодолимое желание спать — это желание, стоит заметить, преследовало меня постоянно, — я поплелась домой**.

Будет ли постановка запятой после слова «постоянно» считаться правильной?
Эта запятая стоит для того, чтобы отделить деепричастный оборот от основной части предложения, несмотря на вставную конструкцию?

Answer (score 2):

***Сославшись на непреодолимое желание спать — это желание, стоит заметить, преследовало меня постоянно, — я поплелась домой.***

Да, знаки поставлены верно, запятая закрывает деепричастный оборот. Вставная конструкция выделена с помощью двух тире.

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176)  В большинстве случаев каждый из этих знаков препинания [запятая и тире - Е.К.] ставится на собственном основании:
*Увы! Моя шкатулка, шашка с серебряной оправой, дагестанский кинжал, подарок приятеля, — всё исчезло* (Л.) — запятая закрывает обособленное приложение, тире поставлено перед обобщающим словом после перечисления однородных членов предложения;
*Его походка была небрежна и ленива, но я заметил, что он не размахивал руками, — первый признак некоторой скрытности характера* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения, тире поставлено перед своеобразным приложением к предшествующим словам, имеет присоединительный оттенок;
*Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали* (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть, тире поставлено перед частью предложения, выражающей следствие.